# NServicebus hosted in Azure Worker Role not working

Tags: nservicebus, azure-worker-roles

I am probably missing something obvious with this problem, but i can't seem to get an endpoint deployed as an azure worker role to work in a production environment; it works just fine under the local azure emulator.

Here are the steps i took to duplicate this issue using one of the sample projects that ship with the nservicebus samples:

1. downloaded samples from the 3.2.8 build.
2. Used the AzurePubSub example and changed the configuration in the web and worker role to use an actual storage location and not local development storage.
3. Ran locally using the local compute emulator to verify that the web role and worker role worked as expected.
4. Deployed to a production environment. web role works and places messages on the queue as expected but the worker role does not handle the message.

there are no exceptions and the worker role deploys and starts as expected; it just doesn't seem to be handling messages.

I am hoping i am missing something simple and someone has come across this problem before.

**Update**: 
I see that the below log entry is in the role's event log. Is the problem simply that the default logging profile trying to access 127.0.0.1:10000?

Here is the profile that the sample is configure to use:

```
NServiceBus.Production NServiceBus.OnAzureTableStorage NServiceBus.WithAzureStorageQueues
```

And here is the full event log entry:

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.Exception Process ID: 2512
Process Name: WaWorkerHost
Thread ID: 6
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role OrderService_IN_0
Exception: Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start()
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Azure.RoleEntryPoint.Run()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<StartRole>b__1()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Inner Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.Management.RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager.<.ctor>b__2(Object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.ControlChannel.GetControlContainer()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.ControlChannel.set_StartupInfo(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo value)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.Management.RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager..ctor(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, String deploymentId, String roleName, String roleInstanceId)
   at NServiceBus.Integration.Azure.AzureAppender.ConfigureAzureDiagnostics()
   at NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(Configure config, Object appenderSkeleton)
   at NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net[TAppender](Configure config, Action`1 initializeAppender)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Profiles.ProfileManager.ActivateProfileHandlers()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize()
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start()

Inner Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
```

**Update - Resolution:**
The problem was that the sample project that i was using as a baseline used an older connection string identifier name "Diagnostics.ConnectionString" and the NServiceBus Azure Logging Appender was looking for the newer azure identifier that designates diagnostics storage location "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString." Renaming the identifier resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of azure support in nservicebus. Let me help you with figuring this out, something must go wrong and there are a few ways to figure out what.

1. Log on to the worker using RDP and check the machine event log for any exception originating from your worker process.
2. Deploy with windows azure diagnostics and check the logs written to table storage
3. Deploy with intellitrace and download the stack traces from the worker to do a remote debugging session.

Comment: Added the stack trace from event log. Looks to be the default logging profile is trying to log to local storage. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, looks like diagnostics is trying to access dev storage. Can you add a setting to csdef and cscfg for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString and point it to your storage account? That should fix it.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString already has a storage location specified. I also had tried removing diagnostics logging altogether. So you are thinking that the NServiceBus.Integration.Azure.AzureAppender.ConfigureAzureDiagnostics() call in the stack trace enlists using the azure diagnostics connection string?

Comment: Yes, the azure appender uses the azure diagnostics connection string if available and otherwise defaults to devstorage. See https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/3.2.8/src/azure/Integration/NServiceBus.Integration.Azure/AzureAppender.cs. So looks like it can't find the connectionstring in the configuration.

Comment: PS: using the development profile will log to console instead of dev storage, setting that would effectively disable logging.

Comment: interesting. not sure if this is a change with 1.7 but enabling diagnostics will create an entry in the csdef that is named "Diagnostics.ConnectionString" which is different than what the appender is looking for (and what used to be created when diagnostics was selected in a azure configuration) "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" I will change it to the fully qualified configuration name and see if that resolved the issue.

Comment: That's the key used back in the early days of azure, I believe SDK & tooling v1.3 and before.

Comment: yes. Thank you for your help! In hindsight i think what tripped me up is that i started with the sample project which has the older Diagnostics.ConnectionString used (lines 22 and 41 of the sample's csdef file). Removing those lines and adding the new conventions resolved the issue.

Comment: I'll check and make sure those are removed from the sample, they're not valid anymore